# Where would I implement a generic method, to be used by 3 different View Controllers?

Tags: objective-c, ios, generics, implementation

I have **3 ViewControllers**.

Each of these controllers needs to perform calculations on a given **Core Data Object**.

These calculations, vary considering the type of object and the controller.

The methods are,

```
performTimeOperations:(Year *) // VC1
performTimeOperations:(Month *) // VC2
performTimeOperations:(Day *) // VC3
```

It's about 50 lines of code for each one.

But the changes in code for each of them, are so small, that I really wanted to pass an ID, like this,

```
performTimeOperations:(id)
```

And make it handle every type of object I throw at it.

Mostly because every change I make, I have to do it in 3 places.

Where would you implement this? And how?

Should I be looking at categories? I also don't think this should go in my appDelegate ... But it certainly would be a better place than to have 3 implementations of it?

Any advice is appreciated

Thank you!

Nuno

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not make all your core data objects inherit from a common base class which implements this method?

i.e. instead of

```
Day -> NSManagedObject
Month -> NSManagedObject
Year -> NSManagedObject
```

you would have

```
Day -> MyDateType -> NSManagedObject
Month -> MyDateType -> NSManagedObject
Year -> MyDateType -> NSManagedObject
```

Answer (score 2):

You can either implement varying parts of calculations in your objects, as @deanWombourne said. Or you can just check for object type (class) in your single calculation method. It's up to you where to put this method, you know your code better than us. Maybe you can create eg. Calculator class and put calculation method(s) there.

Comment: A helper class was my second option and, in hindsight, it would be much easier to unit test your solution than mine :) +1!

Comment: nice, @mifki I did try to implement a class "TimeCalculator", but it was looking so lonely with no sense of belonging. Didn't seem right lol

Answer (score 0):

Two options, the C way:

```
id doYourThing(id arg) {
   //50 lines of code on the screen
   //50 lines of code on the ...
   return anAnswer;
}
```

The static method way:

```
@interface AnAppropriateClass : NSSomething 
+ (id) doYourThing: (id) arg;
@end

@implementation AnAppropriateClass 
+ (id) doYourThing: (id) arg {
    //50 lines of code on the screen
    //50 lines of code on the ...
    return anAnswer;
}
@end
```

Both of these are

1. faster than using instance methods
2. Produce smaller binaries
3. Have smaller runtime memory footprints